# How to use regex to redirect all pages of one site to another (using Redirection WP plugin)?

Tags: regex, wordpress, redirect

I need to redirect all pages of site /old-domain/ to /new-domain/ and am having difficulty figuring out simple regex using the redirection plugin for Wordpress. Googling hasn't helped, or I'm missing something basic.

For instance, I would like to redirect
/old-domain/photos/cats TO: /new-domain/photos/cats

and /old-domain/products/shoes TO: /new-domain/products/shoes

I though I should enter:
old-domain/(.*) > new-domain/$1

But that had no effect.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Does not seem to be a regex problem. According to the docs, it should work. https://redirection.me/support/redirect-regular-expressions/ However, is the path "old-domain..." or "/old-domain..."? Pay attention to such details.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for the help. You were absolutely correct about the syntax. Also, you can't put the original domain into the source box.

Here is the answer and syntax in case someone else finds this (I had a very difficult time googling)

To redirect olddomain.com to newdomain.com:

```
/(.*)
http://newdomain.com/$1/
<make sure the regex button is checked>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based upon the examples on https://redirection.me/, it looks like you need a slash at the start to match correctly.

Try:

```
/old-domain/(.*) .... /new-domain/($1)
```